# Typescript Error "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"?

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined, queryselector, typescript-eslint

I have tried solutions present on Stack Overflow but none of them is working for me. I am getting the following error from a TypeScript file

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I am using Angular `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook

I have discovered I am getting error at line `const firstOcc = this.editElem.nativeElement.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted');`

Below is my code

```
@ViewChild('term',{ static: false }) editElem!: ElementRef<HTMLTableDataCellElement>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('Error at below line')
  const firstOcc = this.editElem.nativeElement.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted');

  if (!firstOcc) {return;}
  changeDisplay(firstOcc);

  
}
```

Comment: Can you share what is editElem? I'm assuming its ViewChild?
Also, you can try like this 
 `const firstOcc = this.editElem?.nativeElement.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')`

Comment: Thats right, added code

Comment: `this.editElem` is undefined. If you don't want the error, check if it's undefined before trying to get properties on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code too? maybe there's something wrong. I think I know the exact problem but I need to see your code first @ParitoshM

Comment: @ParitoshM I tried it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example-d2y3kh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Can you kindly update with yout HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... check if the editElem is defined first:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('Error at below line')
  if(this.editElem)
  {
       const firstOcc = this.editElem.nativeElement.querySelector<HTMLElement> 
       ('.highlighted');

     if (!firstOcc) {return;}
     changeDisplay(firstOcc);

  
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you got something like this in your HTML. If your uploading your HTML I can show you an example with your code.

```
<hello  name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p class="highlighted">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

or

```
<hello #term name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p class="highlighted">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

but you need to use it like this

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<div #term> #term <--- for the ViewChild

  <div class="highlighted">asdasd</div> <---- class highlighted
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</div>
```

so that means the highlighted class is in the #term(div). It should work like that.

Hopefully that will help you.